# Hiding files from git-- possible without adding to .gitignore?

Tags: git

I have a couple of files I've just added to a directory that's part of a git repo.  I'd like to hide them from the repo.

I could add them to .gitignore but is there another way?  These are one-offs and it would be ideal if I could keep the .gitignore from having to list them.

Comment: You could manually add each file for tracking if you're masochistic.

Comment: You could put them in your global gitignore. It's probably not ideal but it keeps them out of your repo's gitignore.

Answer (score 10):

You have many places to specify the ignored files. See `man gitignore` for details:

- `.gitignore`.
- $`XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore` or whatever `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` points to, if it exists.
- configuration variable `core.excludesfile`. Note that this option can be set globally or in the local copy of the project.
- some low-level commands have a command line switch for that (but most usual commands do not).

But note that, contrary to some other VCS, you can have one `.gitignore` on each directory of the project tree. Maybe your reticence to use the `.gitignore` is because you do not want to use the file in the root directory of your project.